# how do I add a hyperlink in sms message in android phone?

Tags: android, hyperlink, sms

I want to send a sms message with the message body like "where am I?"
when I click "where am I?",  it will take me to the google map website with my location.
My question is that how can I add this hyperlink in the "where am I?" message text?
Is there any example that I can study?

Comment: I think SMS is just for text.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

SMSes are text-only, and they only allow 160 characters. What you are suggesting would include 'where am I?' in the 160 characters but also somehow include a very long web address.

The first thing you might want to do is make use of some sort of URL-shortening service. I don't have one that I can personally recommend but there are Django apps, among other things, and online services that you can hook into with an API (like bit.ly). That will get you a unique link to easily fit in the available characters of an SMS.

Most smart phones will parse a link and make it 'clickable', even if it is in an SMS. So, for example, you could make the text read:

```
Where am I? www.linkgoesh.ere/somehash
```

The user should be able to click on the link and visit your website. It's not as elegant as what you're suggesting, but SMS is a (necessarily) limited format.

Comment: Thanks, I would try your sugestions!

Comment: I got home and tested it, and yes, if you send an address (e.g., www.loadingreadyrun.com) to an Android phone via SMS, the SMS application will parse it and allow it to be clicked, thereby opening the browser and visiting the address. Works on Desire anyway.

Comment: Just be careful however, as not all devices will replicate this behavior.  An alternative you might want to look into is "Push SMS".  These are designed to push URL's to an SMS client and have the handset automatically open the resource, they are often used to get an MMS client to download an MMS from a server.

Answer (score -4):

Try this code, it should resolve your issue.

```
String uri = "http://maps.google.com/maps?saddr="+latitude +","+longitude;                                  
SmsManager smsManager = SmsManager.getDefault();
StringBuffer smsBody = new StringBuffer();
//long number = Long.parseLong(get_number);
smsBody.append(Uri.parse(uri));
smsManager.sendTextMessage(get_number, null, smsBody.toString(), null, null);
```

Comment: It's customary to add some simple short explanation about the functionality of your code.