# Build a URL and insert it in SMS message using Android

Tags: android, url

I am building an application which creates a SMS from the from the user fills and sends it to the intended person. I want to create a URL to a webpage with parameters collected from the form.

For example: The form has fields `A` and `B`. When the `user1` clicks `'Send'` button, it should generate a URL to a page `www.mypage.com/collect.html?field1=A&field2=B`. I want to insert this URL into the SMS that is sent so that when `user2` clicks on the URL he is redirected to the URL and I can pre-populate the form with the parameters in the URL.

I can generate the URL from the user inputs but how do I insert this URL in the SMS I am sending out? I have a `String` that I am sending as a SMS. For e.g. "Please click here" and I want to encode 'here' with the URL.

Comment: Don't believe this is possible, duplicate question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6500137/how-do-i-add-a-hyperlink-in-sms-message-in-android-phone

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Most likely not going to work. I've tried simple HTML (e.g. `<a href="google.com">Google</a>`) out of interest, but it won't get parsed correctly.

A (not so beautiful) solution would be to send the plain URL or to use an URL shortener service.

[image]

Comment: Your solution seems reasonable. But I somehow want to mask the url in the word 'here' and not show the URL. I think it does not seem possible due to security issues. Directly passing the link can work as the OS on the phone will parse it as a link and open it.

Comment: how can we use a url shortner service from within the app?

Comment: By accessing the API of url shortener services, such as Google's goo.gl. You can find the API reference [here](https://developers.google.com/url-shortener/).